# Document Object Model

Tags: javascript, document

Question is simple but confusing for me that when i console.log(document.body) or (document.head) both are working fine but when i do with document.script or document.html these two are not working why ? although all these things are in the document ?

Q2) i can write

```js
document.getElementById('something')
```

but why i can't write

```js
document.body.getElementById('something')
```

although body is in the document and element in the body tag as well, while sometime document.body works at different stages in script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getElementById` is a method on `document`, which is an object that uses the [`Document`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-document) interface from the DOM. It's not a method on elements (the [`Element`](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element) interface from the DOM and its specialization the [`HTMLElement`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#htmlelement) interface from HTML). `document.body` is an element (an `HTMLBodyElement`, which is an `HTMLElement`, which is an `Element`), not a document.

Some methods (like `querySelector`) are methods on *both* `document` *and* elements, because it makes sense for them to be (on an element, `querySelector` only looks within the element, not throughout the document). But `getElementById` isn't. (It could be, but it would be a bit odd to scope it to just an element when IDs are meant to be unique throughout the document.)

Comment: as you said querySelector are method on both document and elements(like body) so how it make sense on an element and why not getElementById on both ?

Comment: @HaseebJumani: As I said above: *"It could be, but it would be a bit odd to scope it to just an element when IDs are meant to be unique throughout the document."*